# ServiceNow Javascript passing variables from GlideAjax functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, scope, servicenow

I am using ServiceNow. I need to validate a form onSubmit. I am using GlideAjax with a script include to validate data. How can I pass variables from the Ajax function **calendarDate(response)** to other functions within the Client Script? When the glide ajax function returns an error message, I want to set the variable "isValid" to false.

I have done this easily with Client Scripts that do not involve GlideAjax. I simply set the variable isValid to the result of the function such as var isValid = checkLnrDates();

However, setting a variable equal to the function call when using GlideAjax does not return any value that I can use. I perhaps am not understanding the way that the GlideAjax functions are called and handled.

Catalog Client Script onSubmit

```
function onSubmit () {
  var isValid = checkLnrDates();
  if (isValid == false) {
  g_form.submitted = false;
  return false;
  }
}


function checkLnrDates() {
  var start = g_form.getValue('start_date');
  //Check calendar date format valid YYYY-MM-DD
  //Script include ClientDateTimeUtils checks the input data
  var ajaxCalendarDate = new GlideAjax('ClientDateTimeUtils');
  ajaxCalendarDate.addParam('sysparm_name', 'validateCalendarDate');
  ajaxCalendarDate.addParam('sysparm_userDate', start);
  ajaxCalendarDate.getXML(calendarDate);
}


function calendarDate(response){
  //This is where we get the response returned from the ClientDateTimeUtils script include ajax function
  var answer = response.responseXML.documentElement.getAttribute("answer"); 
  if (answer != 'true'){
  g_form.showFieldMsg('start_date', answer,'error');
  //How can I pass the value of a variable to the function above? I want to set isValid to false
isValid = false; 
return false;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you need to get a response from the AJAX round-trip before you can proceed means that you're not actually asynchronous. You could probably just call `ajaxCalendarDate.getXMLWait()` and then call `ajaxCalendarDate.getAnswer()` to get the response synchronously (see [Synchronous GlideAjax](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=GlideAjax#Synchronous_Glide_Ajax))

However, since you're already submitting, and your code relies on a server-side function call to validate some input, you might just consider moving this logic into a Before Insert Business Rule that validates, and aborts using `current.setAbortAction(true)` if your validation fails.
Wiki example [here](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=GlideRecord#setAbortAction&gsc.tab=0).

Your business rule would look something like:

```
function onBefore(current, previous) {
  if (!CliendDateTimeUtils.validateCalendarDate(current.start_date)) {
    current.setAbortAction(true); // Don't save the record
    gs.addErrorMessage("Start date is not valid"); // Add an error message for the user
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice I have switched to using getXMLWait. I have tested it out with ajaxCalendarDate.getAnswer();  and that allows me to pass variables from that function to the onSubmit!!! so I can decide whether to submit the form or not based on that output. Thank you so much Joey.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    function onSubmit(){
      checkLnrDates();
      return false;
    }


    function checkLnrDates() {
      var start = g_form.getValue('start_date');
      //Check calendar date format valid YYYY-MM-DD
      //Script include ClientDateTimeUtils checks the input data
      var ajaxCalendarDate = new GlideAjax('ClientDateTimeUtils');
      ajaxCalendarDate.addParam('sysparm_name', 'validateCalendarDate');
      ajaxCalendarDate.addParam('sysparm_userDate', start);
      ajaxCalendarDate.getXML(calendarDate);
    }


    function calendarDate(response){
      //This is where we get the response returned from the ClientDateTimeUtils script include ajax function
      var answer = response.responseXML.documentElement.getAttribute("answer"); 
      if (answer != 'true'){
          g_form.showFieldMsg('start_date', answer,'error');
         return false;
      }
      else
        g_form.submit();
 }
```

Comment: The ServiceNow equivalent of `document.forms[0].submit();` would be `g_form.submit();`